# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1) while trying to upgrade python?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and currently running python version 2.7.12. I am trying to upgrade it to python 3 . So i run the following commands:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa.
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install python3.6

When i run the third command, i get the following error message:-

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-176 linux-headers-4.4.0-176-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-177 linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-178 linux-headers-4.4.0-178-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-179 linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-184 linux-headers-4.4.0-184-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic linux-image-4.4.0-173-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-174-generic linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic linux-image-4.4.0-177-generic linux-image-4.4.0-178-generic linux-image-4.4.0-179-generic linux-image-4.4.0-184-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-173-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-174-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-176-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-178-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-179-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-184-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-173-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-174-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-176-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-177-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-178-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-179-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-184-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic (4.4.0-185.215) ...
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-185-generic
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-186-generic (4.4.0-186.216) ...
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-186-generic
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic (4.4.0-185.215) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-185-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-185-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.4.0-186-generic (4.4.0-186.216) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-186-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-186-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-186-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-185-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-186-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not quite sure what i am doing wrong. I am new to this so please excuse any naive mistakes. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Problem #1: You are about to destroy your system. Ubuntu 16.04 already has Python3 installed. Use it. DO NOT try to remove or "upgrade" Python2. That will destroy your system. Simply use the Python3 that is already installed.

Comment: Problem #2: Your HDD or partition is full: `gzip: stdout: No space left on device`

Comment: ohh wow!! ouch. that's good to know. Thank you. So if i want to run a command using python3 how do i run it?

Comment: Using Anaconda/Miniconda is the simplest way to do it. It creates a separate python environment and does not touch the system python.